# Storing day and month (without year)

Tags: mysql, database-design

I'm having trouble with figuring out the best way to store some data in my database. I've got to store DD/MM dates in a database, but I'm not sure of the best way to store this so that it can be easily sorted and searched.

Basically a user will be able to save important dates in the format DD/MM, which they will be reminded of closer to the day.

The DATE data type doesn't seem completely appropriate as it includes year, but I can't think of another way of storing this data. It would be possible to include a specific year to the end of all occasions, but this almost doesn't seem right.

Comment: Sorry, but I can't imagine why do you try to avoid year, what's the point of date when you don't know year? But you can use string as a type of field and save month and day in it

Comment: i would use date type, it wont hurt to have a year present even if not used, greater future flexibility, optimised storage etc.

Comment: @Senad I'm not trying to avoid the year, it's just that it isn't data that I'm interested in. For example, I don't need to know that the first official Australia Day was in 1818. Rather I'm just interested in storing that it's on 26/1.

Comment: @SenadMeškin There is a lot of cases where the year is not needed, for example for birthday, i dont want to ask my cutomer the year when they were born, but i want to know month and day to give a present.

Comment: @Sasha, Btw, MySQL also has a [`YEAR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/year.html) type.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

> I've got to store DD/MM dates in a database, but I'm not sure of the best way to store this so that it can be easily sorted and searched.

The best way to store date data, **even if** the year component is not required, is to use date.  When you need to use it, you can remove the year, or replace it with the year being compared against (or current year).

Having it in date column facilitates **sorting correctly, integrity, validation** etc.

To cater for leap years, use a year like '0004' which allows '0004-02-29'.  Using year 4 makes it slightly more complicated than year 0, but as an example, this turns the date '29-Feb' (year agnostic) into a date in this year for comparison with some other field

```
select
    adddate(
    subdate(cast('0004-02-29' as date),
        interval 4 year),
        interval year(curdate()) year)

result: 2011-02-28
```

Comment: Much needed here so registered customers for our CRM can store birthdate on both formats: dd/mm or dd/mm/yyyy. Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `0004` for the year, because MySQL's `DATE` type don't store dates before `1000-01-01`. Use `1000` instead (or any leap year after `1000-01-01`). See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/datetime.html

Comment: @MarceloPascual MySQL is quite happy to use '0004-02-29' as a comparable date or interval, even if it is outside the valid range for storing. Besides, the point of using 0004 is because it's a leap year. Year 1000 is not.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi You're right, 1000 is not a leap year. My mistake. I then suggest using 1004. Even if 0004 is accepted, if docs says that supported range in 1000-01-01 to 9999-12-31, I would go with 1004 :)

Comment: proposed `select adddate(subdate(date('0004/02/29'),interval 4 year),interval 2016 year);` returns 2016-02-**28**. better way: `select adddate(date('0004/02/29'),interval year(now())-4 year);`

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi MySQL cannot happily use older dates as the documents says "For the DATE and DATETIME range descriptions, “supported” means that although earlier values might work, there is no guarantee.".

Answer (score 6):

Are these dates recurring? If not, how will you keep track of when one has "expired"? If the answer is "the app will manually remove the dates once they have expired", then why not simply store the `DD/MM` date as the *next available* instance of that date? For example:

`01/02` becomes `2012-02-01`, and `04\07` becomes `2011-07-04`

The built-in date/time functions are so useful that I strongly recommend you *not* use `varchars` or `tinyints`.

Answer (score 5):

If you really really want to drop the year, then just make TWO columns, one for day and another for month. Then store them separately.

```
CREATE TABLE `table-name` (
  `Day` tinyint NOT NULL,
  `Month` tinyint NOT NULL
);
```

**But, it's much better to just use the `Date` type and then ignore the year in your code.**

Comment: How will he count the number of days from one date to another? He'd need a `Month` table. It would be a disaster.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy, Yes it will surely be a disaster. That's why I am recommending **against** it.

Comment: @ClosureCowboy, shamittomar, There is no disaster. You can do the date calculation yourself too either on the PHP side, or on the MySQL side (stored procs).

Comment: @ClosureCowboy It's ok as long as you create a date object in your language before using it.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it's possible to create a date/time object by column concatenation (e.g.: TIME(CONCAT(tableA.hours, ':', tableA.minutes, ':00') ) . Maybe not the best option, but possible