# What would be the best way to store birthdate(birthday) field with optional year

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have mysql database, with birthdate column as date.

What would be the best way to save into this column, with optional year. Should I just put some random year on it? what is the best practice to save birthday in database.

I create 3 text field in cakephp, day, month, and year.. but not sure how to approach this, to save in database, since if I randomly put the year (maybe 0001, since 0000 is not accepted), when I pull it back, it will show the year.

Comment: personally I'd just use a datetime field, you can still search the database via MONTH(date_column)='12' AND DAY(date_column)='6' and ignore the year part of it as long as you've inserted something generic for that part.

Comment: Here is almost the same question with a good answer.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4998470/storing-day-and-month-without-year

Answer (score 1):

Might it be best to use three columns, Day, Month, and Year, and treat Year as optional?

Edit: Although using two might be cleaner. one DATE column and just put a dummy year in (0000) and one YEAR column. Then assemble the two as you use them. That way you get all the formatting, sorting and data validation that the data types provide, but you can still ignore the year when you don't have it

Comment: I think this option will end up providing the least headache. Basically what you're storing is a birth month, and day of month. As a separate thing, you might also be storing a year. So, the solution to a birth month and day of month is two separate fields. And the solution to a year is another field. Things will get confusing if you put them all into one date field when the year is optional.

Comment: Although using two might be cleaner.  one DATE column and just put a dummy year in (0000) and one YEAR column.   Then assemble the two as you use them.  That way you get all the formatting, sorting and data validation that the data types provide, but you can still ignore the year when you don't have it.

Answer (score 1):

Just an opinion, but if the year is optional (some will have it; some won't) I'd use a `DATE` type and set the year to zero. You can check for birthdays without years like this:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE YEAR(birthdate) = 0
```

Or if the `birthdate` column is indexed use this instead because it'll be optimizable:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE birthdate <= '0000-12-31'
```

If the year is forbidden for all values - in other words you'll never store the year - I'd recommend separate month and day columns.

Comment: I like your approach. I would personally set the year to something like "1900"

Comment: That should work too, but [there will be a few exceptions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oldest_people#Ten_verified_oldest_people_living) :)

Comment: LOL then use 1800. Checkmate!

Comment: Just use three separate fields - day, month, and year, and completely avoid any ambiguity or confusion.

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to have two fields:

1. `birthdate` which is a date
2. `BirthdayHasYear` which is a flag (such as a tinyint)

The reason for not depending on a rule like "when the year is zero then it is unknown" is that the data structure is very hard to understand -- in the future or if someone else looks at it.  I would then be inclined to add a constraint that said "if `BirthDayHasYear` is true then the year on `birthdate` is 0 (or whatever).

Alternatively, I would have one field of `birthdate` and then *only* access the table through a view where such fields as:

- BirthdayHasYear
- Age

are defined as additional fields in the view.  In other databases, I would use this approach with computed columns.