# Insert Date with or without year in any database with Date as column Data type

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to insert a Date into my Date column in my database but may or may not have a year component. Can anyone give me a working custom date format that will insert dates with or without a year into a date column in a table, preferably in Oracle or MySql?

Comment: Many databases here. Which one are you actually using? Tagging everything you can think of doesn't help you like you seem to think.

Answer (score 0):

Pick one year and use that as your convention. Far in the future or far in the past is probably a good idea, but as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4998534/781965) suggests it's best to use the Date data type as it facilitates all the proper date operations (e.g. sorting, comparisons, date arithmetic etc).

That answer also has some good points about using a leap year so you have the full range of dates.

You're not going to be able to use a date format without actually storing the date at all. Just make sure that you access it correctly. Dates are not stored in the kind of format I think you are thinking of. You can convert a formatted date into a date type, but it's all going to be stored as a number of ticks no matter how you input the data.